# Google app engine - app becomes unhealthy due long deployment

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, gcloud

I have been trying to deploy a webapp with GIS data for the past three months. The app is quite heavy, my laptop that is lets say decent runs into some difficult with it, though I can run it locally and apparently I finally could set it up; though I still facing an error.
I am also going for condaenv instead pip, pip and gdal they hecked my head.

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 6.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

liveness_check:
  path: "/liveness_check"
  timeout_sec: 4
  check_interval_sec: 60
  failure_threshold: 10

readiness_check:
  path: "/readiness_check"
  app_start_timeout_sec: 900

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3
```

I declared my ENTRYPOINT in the .yaml file, as it seems to be a better option than do so with the dockerfile.

Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda:latest

WORKDIR /home/reinhold/Documents/webapps/house_market_app/ihm_condaenv

COPY environment.yml ./
COPY app.py ./
COPY boot.sh ./


RUN chmod +x boot.sh \
    && conda env create -f environment.yml \
    && conda install -n base -c defaults conda\
    && echo "source activate ihm_condaenv" > ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH /home/reinhold/anaconda3/envs/ihm_condaenv/bin:$PATH

EXPOSE 8080

#RUN /bin/bash -c "source /home/reinhold/anaconda3/envs/ihm_condaenv/bin/ihm_condaenv.sh"

CMD ["./boot.sh"]

#ENTRYPOINT [“–host=0.0.0.0”, “–admin_host=0.0.0.0” , "app.py"]
```

I am not quite sure if I need to declare the ENTRYPOINT again here, because when I don't do it I will get an error such as the app wasn't startup properly.
Also I declared my ENTRYPOINT in the

boot.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
gunicorn -b :$PORT --access-logfile - --error-logfile - app:app 
#gunicorn -b :8080 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - wsgi:app
```

The error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response:
[4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back.
If you believe this was an error,
try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.
```

I will much appreciate any help 
The [GitHub repo ][https://github.com/Reinhold83/ihm_condaenv#ihm_condaenv]

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is expected, I think you are misunderstanding the concepts.

If you are using [App Engine Flexible Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml), the entrypoint is defined in the Dockerfile as the custom runtime searches for the Dockerfile for the configuration, as you can see in general setting for app.yaml file for custom runtimes, there is no option to define an entrypoint in app.yaml file.

Using [App Engine Flexible Predefined Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) as Python, Java etc , you can specify the entrypoint in the app.yaml as these runtimes did not require Dockerfile for the configuration.

Please let me know for any further questions regarding this.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I had a deeper reading about the subject, I did set up it properly after all with the entrypoint specified in the dockerfile, what I ended up finding out that Flask server isn't good enough to performance hard tasks such as GIS using Bokeh and GeoPandas, so in order to reach such I will need to do something link [RESTFUL API] (https://www.toptal.com/flask/flask-production-recipes) Also unless I use GIS flask is being very useful. Any suggestions to easy on the processing with GIS?

Comment: I'd say Flask when used properly is powerful for almost any application. The performance will depened mainly on how your code is structured and where you are hosting this app. GAE Flex gives you the benefit of customizing your runtime environment in a very detailed way which is useful for GIS apps.

What I suggest, if your GIS app seems to be slow, split it into a separate backend service that acts as an API. An you can play around with the min_idle_instances in your app.yaml. Having a min of 1 means you avoid the cold starts (time until the instance is ready to serve requests)